# How to paint through the mesh during weight painting

Tags: weight-painting

More often than not when I do weight-painting, weights on a model are the same/similar through the whole mesh (for example leg, arm), but weight painting has culling which prevents paint to go through the model and affects only visible part. To rotate around mesh for painting is often less precise and is always time consuming.

How can I switch culling off and be able to paint through the whole mesh during weight paint (similar to texture paint with *Tools -> ProjectPaint -> Occlude*, Cull, Normal all set to Off)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in 2.80 the solution is the options under the brush settings --> **"Front Faces Only"**
[image]

Comment: This has to be combined with 2D falloff.
And yes there's a typo

Comment: tested it and you are right, you think it is bug or a mistake?

Comment: Well there is a difference between Front Faces Only being activated or deactivated once 2D falloff is activated (try painting through a torus). However there is no difference between the two if 2D falloff is deactivated. I don't think it's problematic though. If you brush on back faces with 3D falloff you most likely mean to paint on them. It's just a bit misleading. Perhaps preventing it to paint on back faces all the time would be a nice addition to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by deselecting *Limit selection to visible* from the header. You should now be able to paint through the entire mesh. It doesn't update the opposite side in realtime however as it does when painting, it updates when you release the mouse.

[image]